# log4j2 custom layout not working with Rolling appender file

Tags: layout, customization, log4j2, rollingfileappender

I'm working with log4j2 and rolling appender file. 
I want to use a customize layout but it's not working properly.

I'm working with JBoss. I have put the lib with the cusotmize layout in the libs directory, so it's in the class path.

In the log4j2.xml, I have put the following configuration:

```
    <Configuration status="trace" packages="mypackage.audit">
     ...
 <Routing name="RoutingAppender">
      <Routes pattern="$${ctx:FlowName">

    <Route>
          <RollingFile name="Rolling-${ctx:FlowName}" fileName="logs/Audit-${ctx:FlowName}.log"
                filePattern="./logs/Audit-${ctx:FlowName}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz" >
                <PatternLayout>
                     <pattern>%d{ISO8601} [%t] %p %c{3} - %m%n</pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <Policies>
                  <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="6" modulate="true" />
                </Policies>
                <Layout type="AuditLayout" locationInfo="true"/>
         </RollingFile>
     </Route>
  </Routes>
  </Routing>

</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Logger name="CustomizeAuditing" level="info" >
        <AppenderRef ref="RoutingAppender"/>
    </Logger>
</Loggers>


    </Configuration>
```

But nothing is logged correctly!

Thanks in advance

Jamila

Answer (score 2):

following worked for me:
log4j2 version 2.2

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Configuration packages="com.redknee.bssauto.helpers"> 
<Appenders> 
<RollingFile name="Rolling-default" fileName="logs/bssauto.html"
   filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/bssauto-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
<CustomHTMLLayout charset="UTF-8" title="BSSAuto Logs" locationInfo="true" />
 <Policies>
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
      <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
 </Policies>
</RollingFile>      
</Appenders> 
<Loggers> 
<Root level="trace"> 
  <AppenderRef ref="Rolling-default"/>
</Root> 
</Loggers> 
</Configuration>
```

Notice following

```
<Configuration packages="com.redknee.bssauto.helpers">
```

here packages should have all packages containing custom class for layouts

```
<CustomHTMLLayout charset="UTF-8" title="BSSAuto Logs" locationInfo="true" />
```

and CustomHTMLLayout is custom class created by extending AbstractStringLayout